# Clearing Labels in a Group Box by keywords contained in Label Name C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and visual studio.
I am looking to clear some labels in a group box using a key word in label name that is common among all labels I wish to clear.

My current code is:

```
        foreach (Control c in BookingSummaryGroupBox.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                c.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

But it obviously  clears all labels.

Any other ways without changing control types and writing out each line to identify every individual Label to clear?

Thanks. 
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is another if-statement to check for the key word in the label name.

```
foreach (Control c in BookingSummaryGroupBox.Controls)
{
    if (c is label && c.Name.Contains("yourKey"))
    {
        c.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Also if you only want to loop through the labels within the groupbox, you could use a loop like this:

```
foreach (Label lbl in BookingSummaryGroupBox.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (lbl.Name.Contains("yourKey"))
    {
        lbl.Text = "";
    }
}
```